# multiple htmlspecialchars code on one line

Tags: rss, htmlspecialchars

I was setting up an rss feed with a module on joomla (mediarss).  I managed to add some custom codes, my question now is, can I use multiple htmlspecialchars codes/fields in one line.

Herunder, the example :

```
$feed.= "        <title>".htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(strtr($this->items[$i]->title,"\n\r","  ")))."</title>\n";
$feed.= "        <region>".htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(strtr($this->items[$i]->region,"\n\r","  ")))."</region>\n";
```

The first feed is showing me the title of a post in the rss feed, the second one is showing off a region.  The region field is a custom field we added in the backend of joomla.

in the rss feed, this is showing of like this:

```
<title>the title of the post</title>

<region>the region filled in, in the custom field 'region'</region>
```

What I want to achieve is following output

```
<title>the title of the post **in** the region filled in, in the custom field 'region' </title>
```

so can I put the 2 codes on one line?

Many thanks,

Comment: Update: I already found the solution to put all on one line:

`$feed.= "        <title>".htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(strtr($this->items[$i]->title,"\n\r","  "))). "in" .htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(strtr($this->items[$i]->region,"\n\r","  ")))."</title>\n"; `

but now there is no space between the title and the region (in the example i added "in" there should be a space in front and after it?

Comment: Then add a space before and after the quotes to have `" in "`